# printf newline to ignore file

Tags: gitignore, cat, ignore

I have this:

```
printf '.git\nfoo' > .deployignore
```

but then I do:

```
cat .deployignore
```

and all I see is:

> .git

I was expecting:

> ```
> .git
> foo
> ```

anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, it's because we should add a trailing newline:

```
printf '.git\nfoo\n' > .deployignore
```

is better then it's easier to read in a shell with `cat`